# "Against traffic" or "Against the traffic"

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, meaning-in-context, articles

The following first sentence comes from Wikipedia, which 'the' is not used before 'traffic', while the second one comes from BBC, which has 'the' before 'traffic'. I wonder if both usages are correct or not? If yes, is there a difference between these two sentences with and without 'the'? If no, which one is correct ?

> 1. For cycling in particular, collisions at intersections (defined broadly as "not only the junction of two roadways, but also points where driveways, sidewalks, or paths meet a roadway, or where sidewalks or paths meet a driveway") while traveling in the wrong direction **[against traffic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicular_cycling)** has been determined to be over three times more likely for wrong-way cyclists.
> 2. The van was then spotted joining the M4 at junction 15 (Swindon east), driving **[against the traffic](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/england/wiltshire/4372808.stm)** towards London on the westbound carriageway.

Comment: Both versions are grammatical. Because the second one is specific (we have an actual van facing oncoming traffic), the article would normally be present - it's not just *any* traffic, it's the traffic going that way down the M4. In the first one it really could be any traffic, because it's a general statement - in such constructions it's not uncommon to omit the article because no particular traffic is being singled out for reference.

Comment: I will simply cite the American Automobile Association's [riding the wrong way against traffic](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=g2YEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA8&dq=%22way+against+traffic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VXw8T6qtCsrD0QXaro3DBw&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22way%20against%20traffic%22&f=false) to show that not *all* Americans are so wedded to use of the article in all contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I disagree; I would have used "driving against traffic", not "driving against the traffic", in the BBC example. To me the BBC example, as worded, sounds like "driving against {the traffic towards London}", but it's actually "driving {against the traffic} {towards London}". (I imagine this is a U.S./U.K. difference. I'm American.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: (To be clear, your last comment is based on a misunderstanding of my now-deleted comment.)

Comment: @ruakh: oic. Well, actually, I don't really. [IGI Global](http://www.igi-global.com/) seem to be basically American, in that their HQ is at *701 East Chocolate Avenue, Hershey, PA* (great address! :). And they have *driving mistakes (driving against the traffic)* in [this report](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=C88h9E3vnwMC&pg=PT116&dq=%22driving+against+the+traffic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wgU9T_-jJOnG0QXLzMzUBw&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22driving%20against%20the%20traffic%22&f=false). Both forms seem to be valid in the US as well as the UK.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: To be sure, I don't think that "driving against the traffic" is invalid; it's just that I don't think U.S. English draws the distinction you drew in your initial comment, and personally, I would say "driving against traffic" for both situations that you describe. (Or "driving against the flow of traffic", which does have a *the*, but again, not with the distinction you draw.)

Comment: @@ruakh: I wouldn't want to say there *isn't* a significant difference between US/UK usage in this respect, but I respectfully suggest this doesn't seem particularly likely to me. I'll try to think of a more general case that can be set out and either attract the attention of one of our contributors specialising in comparative linguistics, or just give us a feel for things by way of voting trends. Of course, things may be skewed if we have on average more "analytical" users from one side of the pond or the other, even after we've allowed for there being more Americans in the first place.

Comment: ...rightly or wrongly, I decided it was probably more of a "linguistics" question, so I've [asked the experts](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/is-there-a-us-uk-difference-in-interpretation-usage-of-compound-verb-phrases-s) over there for an opinion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Re: US/UK difference: You may well be right. I can remember several times that I've encountered some unfamiliar usage in a British source, and thought to myself, "Weird, I've never heard that before! Must be a U.K. thing . . .", only to start encountering it in everyday conversations, the local newspaper, etc., and realize that it must have been there all along without my noticing.

Comment: I dont think the grammatical use of "the" is up for debate. Both sentences are horribly awkward. To me, going against (the) traffic implies you are going the wrong direction in a lane of traffic. But I have heard it used to mean going in the direction that is freest/fastest, wherein the opposite direction is where the bulk of congestion is.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about traffic in general, as a common scenario, not specific to any road or incidence, then you can ommit "the". Example: "You often spot some people going against traffic on the streets near schools, which is very dangerous"

But when you are talking about a particular situation where the story happened and you want to mention traffic on some road, then use "the" to elaborate the incidence ("The" traffic which you talk about Example: "Police patrol saw the guy when they were passing by George Street. He was seen going against the traffic."

Comment: Seems right to me. You *can* (but usually *don't have to*) omit **"the"** if you've no specific traffic flow in mind, but not otherwise.