# What is the term to describe someone who deliberately drives into oncoming traffic?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

According to http://www.cracked.com/article_23248_6-foreign-words-so-dark-there-are-no-english-equivalents.html (warning: sarcasm), there is no English equivalent for "Geisterfahrer", or someone who drives into oncoming traffic. I know there is a Dutch word ("spookrijder"), but apparently there is no succint term for such a driver in English. What would be the best term to describe that? I assume radio has a term for it in their traffic bulletins, but I don't know what they call it.

Example sentence:

> A {Geisterfahrer equivalent} has been spotted on the M4 near Windsor heading towards London. Please keep to the far left and do not overtake other drivers.

Comment: A "wrong-way driver"?

Comment: "Contraflower" .

Comment: By the way, "Geisterfahrer" doesn't only mean *deliberately* driving into oncoming traffic. The person might mistakenly went the wrong way also. Additionally, the official term in German is *Falschfahrer* (literally "wrong drivers"). *Geisterfahrer* is a slang term.

Comment: You're going the wrong way!--How does he know which way we're going? But my real thought for one word is "crazy." Although, having been a near-victim in such a circumstance in Salem, OR, USA, my initial thought was "Holy crap, I think I almost died! That dude wad fu***** insane!"

Comment: And in Danish: spøgelsesbilist=ghost car-driver, is used officially (in warnings from the police on twitter and in the public radio). Usually, the reason is that drivers use the exit-way to drive on to the highway, rather than using the entry-way

Comment: (Can't edit my comment) I should have written freeway or motorway, instead of highway.

Comment: @ermanen : I occasionally hear the term "Geisterfahrer" on radio when I'm in Germany. So while "Falschfahrer" might be the official term, "Geisterfahrer" is widely used, even on the radio.

Comment: @ermanen wait... this is common enough in Germany that there are *two* dedicated words for it? o.O

Comment: @user568458 as mentioned, one is more of a slang term. Just because there are two words to describe the same thing doesn't mean it occurs twice as frequently. Try a search for "wrong-way driver I-95"...

Comment: Probably dead! ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a word for one who drives in the direction opposite the one prescribed for the given lane?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125693/is-there-a-word-for-one-who-drives-in-the-direction-opposite-the-one-prescribed)

Comment: I would call them an idiot

Answer (score 24, accepted):

***Wrong-way driver*** would be understood for someone going against the flow of traffic in the U.S., as in the the 2012 [Wrong Way Driving Special Investigation Report](http://www.ntsb.gov/safety/safety-studies/Documents/SIR1201.pdf) from the National Transportation Safety Board and the [National Wrong-Way Driving Summit](http://cetrans.isg.siue.edu/wwd/). It is the term used, for example, in California law, explicitly in Vehicle Code [21651.1](http://www.leginfo.ca.gov/cgi-bin/displaycode?section=veh&group=21001-22000&file=21650-21664):

> The Department of Transportation… shall update the June 1989 report entitled "Prevention of Wrong-Way Accidents"….  The update shall… include a review of methods studied … to prevent wrong-way drivers from entering state highways

Sadly, this term is all too-common in headlines from just the last week: [Teen pedestrians hit by wrong-way driver](http://www.nbc-2.com/story/30684452/2-teen-pedestrians-hit-by-wrong-way-driver-in-miami); [Wrong-way driver killed in collision](http://www.sfgate.com/news/article/Wrong-way-driver-killed-in-collision-with-big-rig-6667351.php), [Wrong-way driver arrested](http://www.wilx.com/home/headlines/Wrong-Way-Driver-Arrested-in-Eaton-County-360699321.html), [Wrong-way driver causes havoc](http://triblive.com/neighborhoods/yourallekiskivalley/yourallekiskivalleymore/9557503-74/truck-police-wrong), and so on.

I found this term in UK sources as well, but it doesn't seem to last long in headlines— *M1 wrong-way driver named by police* [became](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-leicestershire-34532503) *Albert Newman named as fatal East Midlands M1 crash driver* and *'Wrong way driver' crashes into lorries* [became](http://www.kentonline.co.uk/dartford/news/road-closed-as-wrong-way-45285/) *Car travelling in the wrong direction crashes into lorries*.

Driving *[against traffic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58199)* usually has a different meaning— to be driving opposite peak flow during rush hour— but is also used to describe someone driving in the wrong direction on a road. I don't think it has a commonplace noun form, however.

I searched for *ghost driver* but find no evidence that it is actually used by anyone in the general public or in the transportation industry; I could not turn up a single instance of it on websites about traffic news or regulation, except in Those-Germans-Have-A-Word-For-Everything sidebars.

Comment: Note, however, that *wrong-way driver* doesn't have a connotation of deliberateness.

Comment: According to the comments neither does Geisterfahrer

Comment: This is a superbly researched and comprehensive answer, Choster. Well done!

Answer (score 8):

In the U. S., broadcasters sometimes frame occurrences in this way: "A few minutes ago a wrong-way driver entered the north-bound lanes using an exit ramp on the 101 freeway."

Example: "'Any time there is a wrong-way driver on the freeway, we automatically look for impairment,' said Sgt. Robert Brazas of the State Patrol. It is not known yet whether drugs or alcohol were involved."

http://www.komonews.com/news/local/Wrong-way-driver-arrested-after-I-5-crash-near-Lacey-259525341.html